# Create DataFrame from raw input

Tags: python, dataframe, preprocessor

I am getting data as follows:-

```
$0011:0524-08-2021
$0021:0624-08-2021
&0011:0724-08-2021
&0021:0924-08-2021
$0031:3124-08-2021
&0031:3224-08-2021
$0041:3924-08-2021
&0041:3924-08-2021
$0012:3124-08-2021
&0012:3324-08-2021
```

In `$0011:0524-08-2021`, `$` denotes start of string, `001` denotes ID, `1:05` denotes time, `24-08-2021` denotes date. Similarly `&0011:0624-08-2021` everything is same except `&` denotes end of string.

Taking the above data I want to create a data frame as follows:-

```
1. $0011:0524-08-2021   &0011:0724-08-2021
2. $0021:0624-08-2021   &0021:0924-08-2021
3. $0031:3124-08-2021   &0031:3224-08-2021
4. $0041:3924-08-2021   &0041:3924-08-2021
5. $0012:3124-08-2021   &0012:3324-08-2021
```

Basically I want to sort the entries into a data frame as shown above. There are few conditions that must be satisfied in doing so.

1.) Column1 should have only entries of `$` and Column2 should have only `&` entries.

2.) Both the columns should be arranged in increasing order of time. Column1 with `$` entries
should be arranged in increasing order of time and same goes for column2 with `&` entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting the lines as you shown in your example, you can try:

```py
import pandas as pd


def process_lines(lines):
    buffer = {}
    for line in map(str.strip, lines):
        id_ = line[1:4]
        if line[0] == "$":
            buffer[id_] = line
        elif line[0] == "&" and buffer.get(id_):
            yield buffer[id_], line
            del buffer[id_]


txt = """$0011:0524-08-2021
$0021:0624-08-2021
&0011:0724-08-2021
&0021:0924-08-2021
$0031:3124-08-2021
&0031:3224-08-2021
$0041:3924-08-2021
&0041:3924-08-2021
$0012:3124-08-2021
&0012:3324-08-2021"""

df = pd.DataFrame(process_lines(txt.splitlines()), columns=["A", "B"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                    A                   B
0  $0011:0524-08-2021  &0011:0724-08-2021
1  $0021:0624-08-2021  &0021:0924-08-2021
2  $0031:3124-08-2021  &0031:3224-08-2021
3  $0041:3924-08-2021  &0041:3924-08-2021
4  $0012:3124-08-2021  &0012:3324-08-2021
```

Comment: Can you explain some things of your code. 1.) what does `str.strip do?`  2.) `id_ = line[1:4]` you set 1:4 because there are only 4 ID's in the example I provided?  3.) I will be getting a huge amount of entries, so typing them and storing them in the `txt` variable would take some time don't you think?